# Using onclick attribute and jquery click handler on achor tag making only onclick function calling . can we not have both function as a click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to use more than one click handler for anchor tag . One using "Onclick" attribute handler and second using Jquery click handler .

This is my Html file .

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;

    $("a[href*='google']").click(function(){
    count =count +1;
    alert(" google called" +count);
 });

  function clickThis()
   {
     count = count + 1 ;
     alert("its onclick Function call " +count);
   }
 </script> 
</head>

<body >
  <a id="foo" onclick="clickThis();" href="http://google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It is running only "onclick" handler . I have checked that handler is right selecting the same anchor tag . But its click handler is not running .

It might be the case that jquery line would not be getting parsed .But as time of parsing the html in browser . it goes from top to bottom , so for script tag parsing , our jquery line would be parsed as like variable (count) declaration .

So what would be the reason that Jquery Click handler is not getting executed on clicking the URL .

And if it  execute then what would be the execution order .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot safely manipulate a page until the document is “ready.” [via jqfundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/#chapter-3)

You'll need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href*='google']").click(function(){
        count =count +1;
        alert(" google called" +count);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok .but again my question is if parsing is done from top to bottom and all the code gets executed when it was not  in any function body .Like I tried and count is working without having it inside the ready function . So why is it necessary to put it inside the ready function . 

2 . What would be the execution order is  decided if i also get more click handler using jquery

Comment: ok right . As this time anchor tag was not parsed . So if we put the jquery below the tag . Would it work . i know this is very bad practice only want to clear the concept .

Comment: It is generally considered better practice to put your script as low in the page as possible. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6026730/1134541) for a short explanation and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1795502/1134541) for a more in-depth look.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to $(document).ready():

```
$("a[href*='google']").click(function(){
    count =count +1;
    alert(" google called" +count);
});
```

So it becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='google']").click(function(){
        count =count +1;
        alert(" google called" +count);
    });
});
```

The OnClick event is triggered first followed by the JQuery click event.

Comment: if we have more than jquery click handler like $("a[href*='.com']") or $("a[href*='www']") with their own handler then how execution order is decided between them .

Comment: I've added a fiddle here showing what happens when the click event is inside the DOM and outside - http://jsfiddle.net/sCQ8e/. My understanding is that the <a> tag gets parsed and the onClick event processed, and then the DOM is traversed. Since functions can exist and be called outside of the DOM, they get called first.

Comment: Okay .In your jsfiddle code , call 1 is not coming which is outside of Dom but when i placed the same below the anchor tag, it gets called .Means i think using "Parsing Top-to-Down" approach .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/86TZu/1/  , here  i have updated your code for this .I got the calling sequence Call 2 -> Call 1 -> Call 3 -> Call 4

Answer (score 0):

You have to include you jQuery handler in $(document).ready....

This code should work:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[href*='google']").click(function(){
        count = count +1;
        alert(" google called" +count);
     });
    });

  function clickThis()
   {
     count = count + 1 ;
     alert("its onclick Function call " +count);
   }
 </script> 
</head>

<body >
  <a id="foo" onclick="clickThis();" href="http://google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```