# d3.js doesn't work for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to understand d3 via [this tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/adding-elements)
So, I've downloaded script, named it d3.js and put it in the same directory with index.html
Here is code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.select("body").append("p").text("New paragraph!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I load page, I don't see a new paragraph? What is wrong?

Comment: any error message in console ???

Comment: Maybe you can provide us more information, like the browser you use to test.

Comment: Chrome, no error messages.

Comment: have you tried typing d3 at the console - this will tell if d3 was loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below is how jsFiddle sets up a working, d3-enabled page. I am not sure what exactly causes your problem, but maybe you could try copying the header.

I generally recommend including libs, like d3, via a CDN (e.g. [cloudflare](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/d3/), or d3's own server, as in the fiddle), since the cached version can then be used across site domains (due to its absolute link), without being downloaded every time.

```
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><style    type="text/css"></style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        window.onload=function(){ 
            d3.select("body").append("p").text("New paragraph!");
        }//]]>
    </script>
 </head><body></body></html>
```

You can keep your [script tag at the bottom of the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026645/document-readyfunction-vs-script-at-the-bottom-of-page) though.

Comment: WOrks now, not sure what caused the problem. I'll do some tests and write about results.

Comment: Lol, both fixed mistakes caused wrong functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "caused wrong functionality"? Does it work for you, or are there any new errors?