# The best way to run a function javascript in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please don't duplicate me with: [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

My question have a little difference. I will explain about this.
I has been put all my function on ready funtion like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#liLanguage").find("a").click(function () {
            ChangLanguage(this);
        });
// orther a lot of function here
   LoadDataToGrid();
}
```

It's done well
But, yesterday my PM said: "you don't need put your code in the ready function, you can run without ready function, put in ready function is very crazy and stupid."

I has been read more topic about ready function and window.onload() function. But no where say that we can't run a function in  ready funtion. What's wrong with my code when i put all function in ready funtion?.

This is better

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#liLanguage").find("a").click(function () {
            ChangLanguage(this);
        });
}
```

Or this is better( without ready function)

```
$("#liLanguage").find("a").click(function () {
            ChangLanguage(this);
        });
```

Comment: Neither "crazy" nor "stupid" are valid criticisms. If there is a real problem with a piece of code, a critic should be capable of explaining the difficulty caused by using it.

Comment: Thanks, by the way. Can you tell me run without ready function better or in ready function better? I see all's well done

Comment: If the code shown were included in a script element after the `#liLanguage` element (e.g., at the end of the body), then both versions will work. If the code shown were included in a script element *before* the `#liLanguage` element then only the one with the ready handler would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you put in ready function will better because it's independent where you put your code. For example:

Example 1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        Test();
    });
    function Test() {
       $("#test").click(function (){
            console.log(2);
       })
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id ="test" value = "Test">
</body>
</html>
```

But it will not run if you put code like this.

Example 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Test();
    function Test() {
       $("#test").click(function (){
            console.log(2);
       })
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id ="test" value = "Test">
</body>
</html>
```

It will run ok if you put your script after html.

Example 3:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id ="test" value = "Test">
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Test();
    function Test() {
       $("#test").click(function (){
            console.log(2);
       })
    }
    </script>
```

It's mean: with example 1 you can put javascript any where, you don't need to care about it.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, PMs don't have an engineering background and they like to talk like they do. Try to watch for that.

Now to answer your question, you can simply add your script in the bottom of the HTML instead of in the head. That way your script will load after the DOM is ready each is basically what document.ready does.

Comment: Thanks, I already added my script in the bottom of the HTML, is your mean my code no wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Look at this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026645/document-readyfunction-vs-script-at-the-bottom-of-page