# ASP.NET Bootstrap show modal while loading JS files at the end of body tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, scriptmanager

I am trying to show a bootstrap modal programmatically using ASP.NET.

The problem is that the ScriptManager is before the script loading (I loads the script files at the end of the body). Because of that the ScriptManager code doesn't affect the modal.

This is any way to bypass it without moving the JS files to the head?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you load them at the end of the body?

Comment: To make my website loads faster...

Comment: Can you not just use `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026645/document-readyfunction-vs-script-at-the-bottom-of-page

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It really helped me to figure out the solution.

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out how to run it even without jquery is loaded.

At the `<head>` tag I added:

```
<script>
    function showModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

And in the server side all I have had to do was to call:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myModal", "window.onload = showModal;", true);
```

So now it will run even calling it before any js file is loaded.